# Ruby on Rails: Record Creation from view error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an isolated issue.

I have a table that populates from several different models, it creates links to follow to each respective view.

The code that I have made for each link should be the same, but for some reason, the link isn't showing up under 'Baseline'. I've checked the :create methods for each model, and they mimic each other, and the code from the view is also just a copy - so I'm at a loss as to where to look next. I'm sure that the problem is that the create method is failing, but I don't know where/how.

Here is the code from my view (I'm also pasting the code from FollowUp3Week, because it works):

```
  <% if Baseline.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first != nil %> 
    <%= link_to "edit", baseline_path([Baseline.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first]) %>              
  <% else %>
    <%= Baseline.create(subject_id: sub.subject_id) %> #I left the equal for the screenshot.
  <% end %>
  </td> 

  <td>
  <% if FollowUp3Week.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first != nil %>
    <%= link_to "edit", follow_up3_week_path([FollowUp3Week.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first]) %>
  <% else %>
    <% FollowUp3Week.create(subject_id: sub.subject_id) %>
  <% end %>
  </td>
```

And here is the create method from baselines_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @baseline = Baseline.new(params[:baseline])
    if @baseline.save
      flash[:success] = "Baseline added from create method"
      redirect_to baselines_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I'm also attaching an image of what it looks like. If I remove the equal sign from <%=, the cell will be blank.
[image: an image]

**EDIT.** I'm in the process of removing all of my database queries from the view. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Can you paste more of your view code please? This is not enough to answer your question. FYI, this is insanely horrible Rails code: Logic and queries inside the view.

Comment: Not an answer but a few notes:

`@baseline = Baseline.new(params[:baseline]) # you should be using strong params here`
#There is a better way to write this`

`Baseline.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first`
`Baseline.find_by(subject_id: sub.subject_id)`
`#it looks like you are making an array here with the [], I bet you just want one object`

`baseline_path([Baseline.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first])`
`baseline_path(Baseline.find_by(subject_id: sub.subject_id))`

Comment: try removing the square brackets I think that's causing you to be showing the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really get that Baseline.where out of your view and into the model. AR scopes from the view is a serious no-no in Rails.

In your baseline mode you could do something like:

```
    def empty_subject(subject_id)
      where(subject_id: subject_id).first != nil 
    end
```

Also, it looks like you're passing arrays into baseline_path and follow_up3_week_path.
Ditch the square brackets.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I feel this is what I should be doing, so I've tried to implement it but was greeted with a NoMethodError. This is a view from the Subject model. Do I need to somehow let the Subject Model know about the Baseline Model?

Comment: Yeah, you should add an association to both models. Something like has_many and belongs_to. Hard to say exactly, but Rails has great documentation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to mark you as the answer because I'm pretty sure the reason my code isn't working is because it's really wrong, and this is certainly a great start.

Comment: So I've already got the associations. The baseline model includes belongs_to :subject and the subject model includes has_one :baseline. However the error is still NoMethodError in Subjects#index. Any idea?

Comment: Did you get rid of the brackets around baseline_path? As long as you have the associations correct and have the id column for both models you can do @baseline.subject. Also, are you getting a baseline object from the controller? You'll need to do that as well.

Comment: I did get rid of the brackets. Should @ baseline.subject work without including something like @ baseline = Baseline.new in the SubjectController? I have both id columns, but maybe I didn't set them up correctly.

Comment: Nope. You have to get @baseline from the controller. Subject model should have column baseline_id and Baseline model should have column subject_id

Comment: Subject was missing baseline_id. I haven't got it to work yet though.

Answer (score 1):

on Baseline model, put this

```
def display_name
  "#{name}" #whatever you like to show including link
end
```